# Have google sheet sort on from submit based on value in second column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have a script that moves rows to a sheet of the same name based on a cell.

I am trying to get this to work `onFormSubmit` but am having no luck.

OnEdit the script works perfectly, but on form submit nothing happens after i submit a form.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let val = range.getValue();
  let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();


  if (col == 2 && val != '') {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
    let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(val);
    let data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    targetSheet.appendRow(data[0]);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `I am trying to get this to work onFormSubmit but am having no luck.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your expected result?

Comment: onFormSubmit nothing happens at all. However it i change the trigger to onEdit and manually change the cell it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the object "e" you get from an onEdit event is different than the one you get from an onFormSubmit event, their fields are different and the way you access their values as well.

The main difference that applies to your code is the way on how you access to the input values of the object e, for **onEdit** triggers you can access the input values with the **e.value** function (when editing 1 cell) and the **e.values** (when editing ranges of cell), whereas for **onFormSubmit** you can only access the input values using the **e.values** (array of values) .

You can see all differences here: [App Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Please try this code:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {

 const values = e.values;

 if (values[1] != '') {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(values[1]);
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1 ,1,1,values.length).setValues([values]);
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
 }
}
```

PS. I tested my code setting trigger by clicking the "clock" icon on the left pane.
[trigger setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gouYd.png)